# How to find the row and column number of a specific cell in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in SQL database and I want to find the location of a cell like a coordinate and vice versa. Here is an example:

```
0 1 2 3                                                                 
1 a b c                                                             
2 g h i                                                              
3 n o j
```

When I ask for `i`, I want to get `row=2 and column=3`. When I ask for a cell of `row=2 and column=3`, I want to get `i`.

Comment: There is no such thing as row and column numbers in sql

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There's a big difference between a database and a spreadsheet. A database is an onordered collection of rows of data, where distinct attributes are put into specific columns. Databases don't have "cells", and the thing you see when you pull database data out of a table doesn't have "cell indexes" like a spreadsheet does. While I could craft a query that technically does what you ask, it's highly unlikely to be what you want. I think this question should be closed as unclear, too broad, or just the fact that it's plain up non-sensical, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store your matrix in table specifying the columns and rows like this

```
create table matrix (
   row int,
   column int,
   value varchar2(20)
);
```

Then you insert your data like this

```
insert into matrix values (1, 1, 'a');
insert into matrix values (1, 2, 'b');
//and so on.
```

And then you can simply find what you need using two queries

```
select column, row from matrix where value = 'i';
select value from matrix where column = 2 and row = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you would do:

```
select "3"
from t
where "0" = 2;
```

Naming columns as numbers is not recommended.  Your whole data model is strange for SQL.  A better representation would be:

```
row    col    val
 1      1      a
 1      2      b
 1      3      c
 2      1      g
 . . .
```

Then you could do:

```
select val
from grid
where row = 2 and col = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key column such as 'id' and for example, the related row is 'col'

```
    select col from db where id = 2;
```

this returns you a specific cell (x,2)